# Isolating certain Docker containers from one another

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-network

I have a couple of containers sitting behind an nginx reverse proxy and while nginx should and can talk to all of the containers, they shouldn't be able to talk to one another. The primary reason for wanting this is that the containers are independent of one another and in the event that one of them gets compromised, at least it won't allow access to the other ones.

Using my limited understanding of networking (even more so with Docker), I naively assumed that creating a separate network for each container and assigning all networks to the nginx container would do the job, though that doesn't seem to work. Here's what my `docker-compose.yml` looks like based on that attempt:

```yaml
services:
  nginx:
    networks:
      - net1
      - net2
      - net3

  container1:
    networks:
      - net1

  container2:
    networks:
      - net2

  container3:
    networks:
      - net3

networks:
  net1:
    name: net1
  net2:
    name: net2
  net3:
    name: net3
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Is it even worth going through the effort of doing it for the sake of security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You idea really works, see next example:

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  nginx:
    image: debian:10
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    networks:
      - net1
      - net2
  container1:
    image: debian:10
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    networks:
      - net1
  container2:
    image: debian:10
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    networks:
      - net2

networks:
  net1:
    name: net1
  net2:
    name: net2
```

**verify:**

```
root@pie:~/20221014# docker-compose exec nginx ping -c 1 container1
PING container1 (172.19.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 20221014_container1_1.net1 (172.19.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.083 ms

--- container1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.083/0.083/0.083/0.000 ms
root@pie:~/20221014# docker-compose exec nginx ping -c 1 container2
PING container2 (172.20.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 20221014_container2_1.net2 (172.20.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.062 ms

--- container2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.062/0.062/0.062/0.000 ms
root@pie:~/20221014# docker-compose exec container1 ping -c 1 container2
ping: container2: Temporary failure in name resolution
root@pie:~/20221014# docker-compose exec container2 ping -c 1 container1
ping: container1: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

And, [networking in compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks) demo an example which same scenario as you:

> The proxy service is isolated from the db service, because they do not share a network in common - only app can talk to both.
>
> ````
> services:   
>   proxy:
>     build: ./proxy
>     networks:
>       - frontend   
>   app:
>     build: ./app
>     networks:
>       - frontend
>       - backend   
>   db:
>     image: postgres
>     networks:
>       - backend
>
> networks:   
>   frontend:
>     # Use a custom driver
>     driver: custom-driver-1   
>   backend:
>     # Use a custom driver which takes special options
>     driver: custom-driver-2
>     driver_opts:
>       foo: "1"
>       bar: "2" ```
> ````

Comment: That's very odd, I swear I had basically same `docker-compose.yml` network setup and I could ping between containers. I recreated all networks and containers and now I'm not longer able to. It's possible that I may have messed up something the first time. Anyways, thanks!